# ayuda con codigo trabado y error ilogico ruby

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

**Saludos. tengo el siguiente problema estaba terminando de validar el siguiente codigo y y me funciona bien si a i le coloco un numero entero funciona pero no me funciona asi tal cual como esta la imagen creo que es un problema del contador ya que si lo omito funciona pero lo necesito para auto incrementar el numero de fila q va leyendo del archivo...... si le coloco 5 en vez de i funciona ya que esa es la linea que valido NADBY. osea el problema no es esa linea es el dato que recibe... adicionalmente intente por consola linea por linea y verifique y segun consola todo esta bien**

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

```
class EncoderController < ApplicationController

  @encoderr = File.foreach('ojos.txt').with_object([]) do |line, result|
    if line.start_with?('NADBY')
      clave     = line[0..4]
      region    = line[6]
      proveedor = line[7...-2]
      cajas     = line[-2..-1]
      result << "#{clave} región #{region}, #{proveedor}, tipo de cajas #{cajas}"

    end
  end
end

     vista ------->>>>>  <h1> <%= @encoderr %> </h1>   <<------------vista
```

Comment: No te muestra nada ya que debes poner la variable `@encoderr` dentro de la acción (e.g `show`, `new`, etc.) que llama a la vista.

Comment: Sí en la vista lo tenia puesto el código y hice varias pruebas con otras variables y si se ven pero esa no se ve? Podría ser mi Ruby on rails con problemas o afecta el entorno Windows?

Comment: No, el entorno de Windows no es problema, ¿qué acción del controlador es y qué vista?

Comment: Bueno el controlador se llama encoder y la vista indexación.

Comment: Solo quería acotar que todos los errores (al menos en el ámbito de la computación) tienen una lógica. No existen los errores ilógicos, por mas que lo parezcan, ya que el 99,99% de las veces el error es tuyo y el resto 0,01% igual es un error que tiene lógica, solo que puede no estar a tu alcance

Comment: coloque eso porque anteriormente habia probado por rails c el mismo comando y por alli me funciono perfecto. no soy nada esperto en rails y me parececio ilogico que por rails c en modo consola me diera el resultado esperado y al ejecutar el rails servers no... me decia error que como me menciono el compañero gerry era q venia vacio yo probe la misma logia en c y funciono.... era por eso... tube q modificar un poco la  pregunta en cuanto me fueron ayudando... de todas formas gracias...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

El problema es que `line_three` es nulo (i.e. `nil`) al momento de llamar el método `start_with?`, asegúrate que `line_three` tenga un *string* asignado antes de ejecutar ese método.

Tu código está muy rebuscado, así que mejor haré una sugerencia sobre el código que podrías utilizar para lograr el mismo resultado:

```
@encoderr = File.foreach('ojo.txt').with_object([]) do |line, result|
  if line.start_with?('NADBY')
    clave     = line[0..4]
    region    = line[6]
    proveedor = line[7...-2]
    cajas     = line[-2..-1]
    result << "#{clave} región #{region}, #{proveedor}, tipo de cajas #{cajas}"
  end
end
```

Este código va a leer cada línea (`line`) del archivo *ojo.txt*, la va a comparar contra la condición `line.start_with?('NADBY')` y, en caso que así sea, agregará la línea al arreglo `result`. Al final, el valor del arreglo `result` será asignado a la variable `@encoderr`.

---

Para optimizar un poco, considero que sería mejor encapsular la lógica en una función, la cual puedes llamar después; por ejemplo:

```
def parse_file(file)
  File.foreach(file).with_object([]) do |line, result|
    if line.start_with? ('NADBY')
      clave     = line[0..4]
      region    = line[6]
      proveedor = line[7...-2]
      cajas     = line[-2..-1]
      result << "#{clave} región #{region}, #{proveedor}, tipo de cajas #{cajas}"
    end
  end
end

puts parse_file('ojo.txt') # Imprime el resultado en pantalla
```

Suponiendo que el contenido del archivo *ojo.txt* es:

```
NADSU 78000mc0cl0Css
NADBY 7808810008659
PAT 1 21D 089
NADBY 6808810008657
```

el resultado sería entonces sería:

```
NADBY región 7, 80881000865, tipo de cajas 9
NADBY región 6, 80881000865, tipo de cajas 7
```

---

Para mostrar correctamente cada elemento del arreglo `@encoderr` en una vista, debes iterarlo utilizando `each`, por ejemplo:

```
<% @encoderr.each do |line| %>
  <h1><%= line %></h1>
<% end %>
```

Tomando el ejemplo anterior, esto generaría el siguiente código HTML en tu vista:

```
<h1>NADBY región 7, 80881000865, tipo de cajas 9</h1>
<h1>NADBY región 6, 80881000865, tipo de cajas 7</h1>
```

Comment: @JonathanZambrano ¿Podrías mostrar el código exacto que estás utilizando? He realizado pruebas con el código de mi respuesta y no he tenido problemas.

Comment: claro voy lo anexo a la pregunta

Comment: gerry verifica y ve lo que tengo

Comment: @JonathanZambrano Mira la respuesta actualizada (al final), esto ayudará mostrar cada línea del arreglo correctamente.

Comment: esta linea <% @encoderr.each do |line| %>
  <h1><%= item %></h1>
<% end %> me arroja undefined local variable or method `item' lo cual me imagine no se de donde viene items

Comment: @JonathanZambrano ya lo corregí, debería ser `line`.

Comment: listo funciona perfectamente muchas gracias.... una vez mas.

Comment: sabes que no validamos aca? se nos paso del primer ejemplo... si el codigo es BGMN22000000000000001, SI  si luego de bgm es 220  es una orden sugerida si no es orden simple...si termina en 1 es original o si termina en 9 es cancelacion o 6 es propuesta.... hay un comando para validar algo asi como clave = line.inculir(120) {3..5}